# iOS: @import AnyModule not found after editing class using cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, import, cocoapods, xcode8

I have an Obj-C/Swift project setup that imports modules using cocoapods. In any class where I am importing a framework using the `@import` function I get the error message `SomeModule not found`. However, when I build/run it compiles fine, and the framework works and functions as expected.

The problem here is that it messes me up when I'm trying to write code below the error (i.e., objects appear as ints because the error above messes up the compiler; function auto complete doesn't work, etc). What's weird, if I cmd+s to save the class, the error messages go away. Then the second I start typing again, they reappear.

I've gone as far as removing all of my cocoapods and reinstalling them, but to no avail. This has only been an issue since installing xcode 8.

Anyone have any insight into this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you fix this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for super late response - the only way I found to get around this was to use the "old" style of framework import; i.e.,  ... it seems like some Frameworks just don't play nicely with the @import declaration. @pablo-martinez

If someone has a better solution please feel free to share.